# Is it possible to use two partition for Window-10 so that system software and programs(applications) will be separated

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I will install Windows 10 and would like to do 2 partitions (say C: and D:). I wand my Windows system being located on  "C" drive (that is all programs when the Windows-10 was installed ) and all other applications installed after Windows-10 that will be installed on "D" drive.

Comment: Yes; Most applications will allow you to choose the installation directory.

Comment: Is it make it automatic?. I mean that all applications will be installed on D drive.

Comment: No; It’s not automatic;  there is not function within Windows that would make this possible